# MySQL: Method of mapping a sum result into a status table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want have a table of status values

```
Status     Min      Max
OK         null     8
WARNING    8        12
PANIC!     12       null
```

I want to return the status based on summing a value in another table and seeing which range it is in. The ranges and number of ranges in the above table may be changed.

i.e. > min <= max

I appreciate this question is a little vague, partly as it's work related, but ideas on how I can map the sum value into the resulting status would be appreciated. Its a sort of table driven case statement that I am hoping to achieve here.

e.g.

```
SELECT id, SUM(column) GROUP BY id
```

then map results into status table to get a list of IDs and their corresponding status

```
id   sum   status
1    6     OK
2    13    PANIC!
3    9     WARNING
```

There could be about 30,000 ids on which I need to sum values and derive a status for each id

Comment: Example data would help

Comment: I don't think its necessary, just take any column of values, take their sum, map it into the table somehow. I['ve given a SQL statement that would be an example use

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select status from statuses values where 
(min is null or min > (select count(*) from othertable)) and
(max is null or max <= (select count(*) from othertable));
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I'll try it later. Possible concerns are the repeated subqueries...